# Can't run Flutter web on Chrome Device with BluetoothThermalPrinter package

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, thermal-printer

Can't run my flutter web app when [blue_thermal_printer](https://stackoverflow.com) package is being used.
Compiler show these errors:

```
import 'package:blue_thermal_printer/';
       ^
/D:/All%20Data/Softwares/Latest%20Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/blue_thermal_printer-1.1.8/lib/blue_thermal_printer.dart:189:23:
Error: Type 'Registrar' not found.
  static registerWith(Registrar value){
                      ^^^^^^^^^
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart:31:3: Error: Getter not found: 'BlueThermalPrinterPlugin'.
  BlueThermalPrinterPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
```

What I have tried until now:
**1-** Tried to enable flutter web support with this command: `flutter create .`
**2-** Tried to create a new class BlueThermalPrinterPlugin in the package file *blue_thermal_printer.dart* with the following method:

```
class BlueThermalPrinterPlugin{
  static var nameoo ;
  static registerWith(Registrar value){
    this.nameoo=value;
    return nameoo;
  }
}
```

But that doesn't either helps because sdk generated automatic *generated_plugin_registrant.dart* which produces incomplete import i.e **import 'package:blue_thermal_printer/';** causing compile time issue.

I need to run my flutter app on web which was working fine a few days before.

Comment: The import seems to have a `.dart` with the same name as the package, including other similar packages, but the error message in the question doesn't have it. For example, why not try the contents shown in those examples without changing anything other than the device name? [blue_thermal_printer 1.1.8](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer), [bluetooth_print 3.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print), [esc_pos_printer 4.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer), [esc_pos_bluetooth 0.4.1](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth)

Comment: Code isn't working with other packages. Any other recommendation with this blue_thermal_printer package?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the developer of this package whom I contacted personally and he corrected the error in packge. **blue_thermal_printer 1.2.0** is working fine and doesn't contain this error anymore.